# TypeScript generic default type vs Contextual Typing

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In TypeScript, we have **Contextual Typing**, when a generic type is not defined, TypeScript will try to infer the correct type from the return value.

In most cases, it works fine. But sometimes it becomes strange. In my case, when a function parameter is undefined, sometimes the generic default type is not used, and it's not expected.

Example & [TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGxoF4oG8oGMD2BXAdsAFxT64C2ARhAE5QC%20UAsAFCsAmEmANvDdADMCmYAEts%20KAGdR5MNwgAeACpRUcRBAB8ACilcJ7APwllASlMBuVjnxTg6LHkIkcBYAEEGa6bPkQdM2YWAHoQqFFJABYAOgAGAGo1LSd3DxIyKlpWMIjJAGYYgE5k1MJ0qHh8EGs2Fk4ePkFhMQknOQUAD0UAWQAaKFV1BCRdAVEaexJ%206QN8Y1MLQdrbe0c3FzLgACFvVBwOiE6dAEYzGwk1%2000fA-9jgCZz0PCNnZIqmpzw66QSDDeGQo1Do9FYQA)

```js
type State = { count: number } 

declare function simple<T = State>(second?: T): T;
const { count: countA } = simple() 
// in 4.0+ => countA: number
// in 3.9 => countA: any;

declare function complex<M, T = State>(first: M, second?: T): T;
const { count: countB } = complex(1)
// countB: any;
```

I would like to ask, is this a TypeScript bug, or is there some kind of **priority** to determine which type to infer from, *the return type* or *the generic default type*?

Answer (score 0):

> is this a TypeScript bug, or is there some kind of **priority** to determine which type to infer from, *the return type or the generic default type?*

This seems like a TS bug with destructuring assignment to me. `const {b} = fn();` should be equivalent to `const tmp = fn(); const {b} = tmp` or to `const b = fn().b`. I have absolutely no idea why writing it as `const {b} = fn()` would break the inferred types.

```
type State = { count: number } 
declare function complex<M, T = State>(first: M, second?: T): T;
const { count: countB } = complex(1) // FAILS
const state = complex(2); // works!
const {count: countC} = state;
const countD = complex(3).count; // works!
let tmp;
const { count: countE } = tmp = complex(4); // works!
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGxoF4oG8oGMD2BXAdsAFxT64C2ARhAE5QC+UAsAFAAmEmANvDdAGYFMwAJbZ8WbOTBcIADwA8AWQA0UACpRUcRBAB8ACn4iaAZ2JRVUU53FsA-CXUBKJwG5WOfOfSSCFnH8AIQYtSWlZOQMARmcoAHp4qAAxAEEASQAZGE9xH3NdMJwI+QMAJmc3BKSAd2waAGtTAEJc72B0QMISLuAAYUZUAqQPFi8fXoARIqkZUoBmZwA6XqrEqDrGltZZDuBpUfGOjF6evEIAUVDUfbAZkqiAFkrqjfqm1pYgA)

Comment: `const {b} = fn();` `const tmp = fn(); const {b} = tmp` are semantically identical on JS

But the different type of return value will affect the type infer in TS;

Comment: Thanks for your answer, maybe it's time to raise an issue in TS commuity [A more practical example](https://tsplay.dev/w26K8w)